# Software for recognizing clothing items' brands and makes

Tags: image-recognition

I've used Google Goggles to take some pictures of buildings but it doesn't always work as well (and sometimes even gives some results a few days later). What I would like is to be able to take a few pictures of clothing items (e.g. shoes which may no longer be manufactured). The program should return the brand and model make, so that I can look for the same items on eBay. I don't know whether this is asking too much (pattern recognition software may not have reached that stage yet).

Please let me know.